# How can I create Database and Tables within a Java application?

Tags: java, sql, database, hsqldb, derby

I would like to create a program in Java, that manipulates data and saves them physically on disk(in text file). I would like to create a simple program that allows you to insert a course, edit it, delete it. The program is stand-alone, so I would create an internal database in the application, create and save various tables with data on the user machine's, so that I can use the program on any computer.
How can I do it? I tried to take a look in the forum, and I found that Derby or HSQL can do these things; I tried to read the documentation and do some testing, but I just can not understand (I'm at the beginning), where data is saved? in which file? where tables are created?
If you can give me a help I would be grateful, even with a few simple example of creating a database and a simple table.
My question is: I would  my program (executable), had within the structure of the database, and on each machine where I run I can insert, edit, delete a course, then create the various tables on the computer that I'm using. How can I do it?
Thank you so much for your patience and for your help.

Comment: Can you clarify exactly what you are trying to do?

Comment: I want to create a simple Java program (with the Java Swing), an executable, in which I can insert, delete, and modify a course and view the data stored. After entering a course in table COURSE, I would that the table, was first created on the machine of those who use the program and then save the data in that table. It is a program that manage a simple course (which is characterized by a name, arguments, duration..). If I decide to execute the program on another computer, when I insert a course, the table will be created on that computer and the data stored in that table. Thank you so much

Answer (score 1):

You can do it easily.

The general algorythm will be the following :

- start program
- test presence/connection to database => ask to create a new database if file  backed, or ask for a new connection
- test existence of tables (exception on a simple select) => launch table creation commands in JDBC (*)
- normal processing

(*) my create tables script generally begin with `DROP ... IF EXISTS` to start from a clean place

Answer (score 0):

just to start as a beginner create a program and save that data in any `.txt` file with java code using `filing`. make sure that make your classes `serializable`. and then you can get, edit and delete from that.